# Array to string conversion en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy intentando almacenar datos después de que el usuario inicia sesion en una tabla (sin utilizar migraciones), estoy utilizando el método authenticated que viene dentro del trait AuthenticatesUsers, este es mi código:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request,$user){
    $agent = new Agent();
    $plataforma = $agent->platform();//get SO
    $browser = $agent->browser();
    $browser_version = $agent->version($browser);  
    $agente = $plataforma." , ".$browser." ".$browser_version;

    $id = $request->session()->token();
    $ip =  \Request :: getClientIp (true); 
    $dataS = $request->session()->all();

    $table_sesion = new Sesion();
    $table_sesion->session_id = $id;
    $table_sesion->ip_address = $ip;
    $table_sesion->user_agent = $agente;
    $table_sesion->user_data = $dataS;
    $table_sesion->last_activity = now();

    $table_sesion->save();
}
```

Mi modelo solo contiene:

```
class Sesion extends Model
{
    protected $table= "pf_sesion";
}
```

Sin embargo me esta arrojando el siguiente error:

**Array to string conversion**

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Donde formas el `string`, alguna/s de las variables que intentas concatenar no es un `string`. Viendo que le pasas `$browser` al método para sacar al versión, puede que ese sea el culpable.

Hay poca documentación con respecto a que devuelve cada método de esa clase, pero lo mejor es que pruebes haciendo `var_dump()` de esas 3 variables y mires cual es el culpable.

```
$plataforma = $agent->platform(); //get SO
$browser = $agent->browser(); // Tiene pinta de ser un objeto
$browser_version = $agent->version($browser);  

$agente = $plataforma . " , " . $browser . " " . $browser_version;
```

Comment: Ya vi cual es el problema, es en la parte del **$request->session()->all()** me esta trayendo un arreglo asociativo. Las otras variables si son de tipo string.

Comment: En ese caso haz una respuesta con la solución y marcala como buena.

Comment: @AndreaEscobar no conozco casi nada de Laravel, pero, ¿por qué usas `$request->session()->all()`? ¿Eso no devolvería algo así como todas las sesiones? ¿No serían los datos de sesión ese usuario lo que habría que traer?

Comment: @A.Cedano `$request->session()->all()` Devuelve todos los datos de la sesión del usuario, algo que puede guardar sin problemas en la tabla si la declaro como JSON en la migración, pero parece que declaro la columna como texto.

Comment: Gracias por el dato @FranciscoGarrido, no lo sabía. Ya eso depende de lo que quiera implementar en su lógica y de qué datos específicos necesite ahí, si todos los datos de la sesión del usuario o parte de ellos.

Comment: Exacto, es que me solicitan los datos de sesión del usuario que inicio sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el error al hacer var_dump a todas las variables que declare, las variables que obtienen el navegador, la versión y el sistema operativo devuelven un string, por lo que no hay problema con la librería que utilice Jenssegers\Agent para obtenerlos datos.

Pero la variable dataS devuelve todo un array con el contenido de los datos de la sesión del usuario. He ahí el error.